# Different proxy for different hosts in gradle with android studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, build.gradle, citrix

I am using two repository for my project dpependencies, one is maven repository and one is my office repository which I am connecting through citrix.

In windows 8 to connect on VPN I have to set 127.0.0.1 as my proxy and 3128 as port and for public network, I am using proxy.mydomian.com and 8080 as port.

Now some dependency in project are on public and some are on office.

I am setting following in **gradle properties** file

> systemProp.http.proxyHost=proxy.mydomain.com 
>   systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
>   systemProp.http.proxyUser=domain\username
>   systemProp.http.proxyPassword=Password
>   systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost|vpn_repo_url
>   systemProp.https.proxyHost=proxy.mydomain.com
>   systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
>   systemProp.http.proxyUser=domain\username
>   systemProp.http.proxyPassword=Password
>   systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost|vpn_repo_url

Now I can one proxy settings at a time, Is there any way to use 127.0.0.1 and 3128 port for only my vpn_repo_url and proxy.mydomain.com for rest.

**Note** It is working fine in Windows 7 with host in no proxy but not in windows 8.

Any other workaroud also will help.